# Using Kotlin Coroutines to Speed up List.find()

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

My goal: For really large lists say 10 million can I leverage coroutines to search different chunks of the list?

Results so far: .find() still is the fastest at about 27 ms but I would expect the coroutines to be faster if there were say 4 coroutines each searching in a different chunk using deferred awaitall. The coroutine method I made is actually taking longer about 73 ms in total.

I understand that we are talking in milliseconds but it's more about the concept that I am concerned with.

Can anyone clarify where I may be going wrong or explain why the coroutines are taking longer? Is it because or coroutine creation? Could it be because sublist is adding time?

```
private suspend fun <T> List<T>.find(
    numberOfCoroutines: Int,
    dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    matcher: (T)->Boolean
): T?{
    return coroutineScope.async {
        val coroutinesToUse = if(this@find.size < numberOfCoroutines){
            1
        }else{
            numberOfCoroutines
        }
        // will always truncate down
        val splitIncrement = this@find.size / numberOfCoroutines
        val listOfDeferred = mutableListOf<Deferred<T?>>()
        for (index in (0 until coroutinesToUse)) {
            listOfDeferred.add(coroutineScope.async(dispatcher) deferredScope@ {
                if(index == numberOfCoroutines-1){
                    println("end[${splitIncrement * index}] to [${this@find.size}]")
                    return@deferredScope subList(splitIncrement * index, this@find.size).find { matcher(it) }
                }else{
                    println("[${splitIncrement * index}] to [${splitIncrement * (index+1)}]")
                    return@deferredScope subList(splitIncrement * index, splitIncrement * index+1).find { matcher(it) }
                }
            })
        }
        // wait for all and return first value.
        for (t in listOfDeferred.awaitAll()) {
            t?.let {
                return@async it
            }
        }
        return@async null
    }.await()
}
```

Comment: How are you measuring the amount of time it takes?  I'd suspect bad measurements first.  That said, coroutines aren't necessarily great at splitting up CPU-bound work; in particular, this may not be running multithreaded at all, since there aren't any suspension points.  Using Java parallel streams might be your best bet, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had some things wrong, I also switched from sublist to while for O(1) access.

The results on a PC with 4 cores using a list of 10 million ints after 200 iterations came to on average: find[8.625 ms] findCoroutines[0.355 ms].

Coroutines increase by about a factor of 24 but in the end it is only a difference of about 8 ms which is not even perceptible IMO.

Here is the final code:

```
private suspend fun <T> List<T>.find(
    numberOfCoroutines: Int,
    dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    matcher: (T)->Boolean
): T?{
    return coroutineScope.async(dispatcher){
        val coroutinesToUse = if(this@find.size < numberOfCoroutines){
            1
        }else{
            numberOfCoroutines
        }
        // will always truncate down
        val splitIncrement = this@find.size / numberOfCoroutines
        val listOfDeferred = mutableListOf<Deferred<T?>>()
        val isFound: AtomicBoolean = AtomicBoolean(false)
        for (index in (0 until coroutinesToUse)) {
            listOfDeferred.add(coroutineScope.async(dispatcher) deferredScope@ {
                var increment = splitIncrement * index
                val endIndex = if(index == numberOfCoroutines-1) this@find.size else (splitIncrement * (index+1))
                    //println("chunk${index+1} [${increment} -> ${endIndex}]")
                while(increment < endIndex){
                    // if it has been found in another chunk return null
                    if(isFound.get()){
                        //println("Found in another chunk, cancel [chunk${index+1}]!")
                        return@deferredScope null
                    }
                    //println("Chunk${index+1} [${this@find[increment]} =?= 9]")
                    if(matcher(this@find[increment])){
                        isFound.set(true)
                        //println("Found in chunk ${index+1}")
                        return@deferredScope this@find[increment]
                    }
                    increment++
                }
                return@deferredScope null
            })
        }
        // wait for all and return first value.
        val resulting = listOfDeferred.awaitAll()
        for (t in resulting) {
            t?.let {
                return@async it
            }
        }
        return@async null
    }.await()
}
```

Comment: I would not expect changing from `subList` to `while` to have a noticeable performance impact.

Comment: Doesn't sublist perform a copy into a new array? Maybe that adds some time? On a 10 mil item array it may add those extra milliseconds. I am not entirely sure.